# Why is the IF statement still executing after it code block falls into the ELSE code block?

Tags: python, thonny

[**Click here for Image of my Code**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7gsE.jpg)

I'm coding a simple text based adventure game, as im still learning the basics of python.
The console is returning an error on line 15. The else condition gets executed on line 14, but it looks like the program still tries to execute, code after line 14. It was my understanding that after an else statement as been executed no if statements within the codeblock would be executed?

```
print("Welcome to Treasure Island.\nYour mission is to find the treasure")

step_1 = input("Would you like to go left or right?")

if step_1.lower() == "left":
    step_2 = input("Swim or wait?")  
    if step_2.lower() == "wait":
       step_3 = input("Which door Red, Yellow or Blue?")
    else:
        print("Attacked by a trout. GAME OVER!") 
    if step_3.lower() == "red":
        print("Burned by fire. Game Over.")
    elif step_3.lower() == "blue":
        print("Eaten by beasts. Game Over.")
    elif step_3.lower() == "yellow":
        print("You Win!")
    else:
        print("Game Over.")     
else:
    print("You have fell into a hole, Game Over!")
```

Comment: Show your code as text in the question itself, not an image or off-site.

Comment: `step_3` might not exist yet when you run there. You should be using a main function - this will make debugging it much easier (also please put your code as text so we can reproduce it ourselves - [mre]).

Comment: Try to refresh Python `if-else` and `if-elif-else` syntax and might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand, what do you mean by "refresh"? im using thonny to enter my python code

Comment: "refresh" in this context presumably means "refresh your memory on", or "reread the documentation regarding".

Comment: You have two _completely separate_ blocks, one if/else and one if/elif/elif/else. Finishing the first block doesn't stop the second block from running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you code, step_3 is only available within the if block on line 11. To fix this you need to declare step_3 above the if blocks, and then assign a value to it in the if block on line 11

Comment: the code executes just fine, if the user input is ("wait") inside step_3 input variable. However if "swim" is entered it should default to the else statement, however it still tries to execute the if statement after its defaulted to else.

Comment: No, python is procedural/imperative here. Once one statement finishes, then next is executed. Once line 14 has finished executing, python continues with line 15. It is only lines 12/14 which are mutually exclusive due to the `if/else` construct around them.

Comment: Oh ok I see your point you need to add exit() to terminate otherwise the program continues to execute after that block.

Comment: @BismarkAsieduAsante: And better than `exit()` would be, as has already been mentioned, to put most of the code into a function and then `return` could be used to stop the program.

Comment: The exit() function did the trick thanks! although in this challenge im only supposed to use what i've been taught thus far as exit commands have not been introduced into the cirriculum at this point. Im still trying to wrap my head around nested if statements, and feel it starts to get confusing the more nested if statements there are, thanks for the help!